# Zookeeper Network Ensemble does not start appropiately

Tags: java, sockets, configuration, apache-zookeeper

I've been working with zookeeper lately to fill a requirement of reliablity in distributed applications. I'm working with three computers and I followed this tutorial:

http://sanjivblogs.blogspot.ie/2011/04/deploying-zookeeper-ensemble.html

I did step by step to ensure I did it well, but now when I start my zookeepers with the

`./zkServer.sh start`

I'm getting these exceptions for all my computers:

```
2013-04-05 21:46:58,995 [myid:2] - WARN [SendWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@679] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1961)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2038)
at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:342)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:831)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$500(QuorumCnxManager.java:62)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:667)
2013-04-05 21:46:58,995 [myid:2] - WARN [SendWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@688] - Send worker leaving thread

2013-04-05 21:47:58,363 [myid:2] - WARN [RecvWorker:3:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@762] - Connection broken for id 3, my id = 2, error = 
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:747)
```

But I don't know what I am doing wrong to get this. My objective is to syncrhonize my zookeepers in different machines to get always an available service. I went to zookeeper.apache.org Web Päge and look for the same information on how to configure and start my zookeeper, but are the same steps I followed before.

If somebody could help me please I would really appretiate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will need to follow some strict steps to achieve this, but finally done it. If somebody is facing the same issue, to make the zookeeper enssemble, please remember:

You need 3 zookeeper servers running (local or over the network), this is the minimum number to achieve the synchronization. In each server, it is needed to create a file called "myid" (inside the zookeeper folder), the content of each myid file must be a sequential number, for instance, I have three zookeeper servers (folders), so I have a myid with content 1, other with content 2 and other with content 3.

Then in the zoo.cfg it is necessary to stablish the parameters required:

```
tickTime=2000
#dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
dataDir=/home/mtataje/var/zookeeper1
clientPort=2184
initLimit=10
syncLimit=20
server.1=192.168.3.41:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.3.41:2889:3889
server.3=192.168.3.41:2995:2999
```

The zoo.cfg varies from each server to another, in my case because I was testing on local, I needed to change the port and the dataDir.

After that, excutes the:

```
./zkServer.sh start
```

Maybe some exceptions will appear, but it is because at least two zookeepers must be synchronized, when you start at least 2 zookeepers, exceptions should be gone.

Best regards.